# On delete item from cart. Minicart counter does not update Magento 2.?

Tags: magento, magento2, cart

I am using MAGENTO 2 and I am working on cart. I am deleting item from cart but main issue i am facing is that. When i delete item from cart magneto successfully delete that product but minicart counter remain same as previous. Shown in picture below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jcau.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by placing a `section.xml` file inside `etc\frontend` directory

Path : `app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\frontend\section.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
  <action name="module/controller/action">
    <section name="cart"/>
</action>
```

As you can see I have placed `module/controller/action`, you can change it according to your custom page URL.